# 2nd monitor not displaying at native resolution

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution

When using my second monitor, I can't get it at full, native, resolution, it only shows an option for 1280x800 instead of 2560x1440. When I disconnect the first monitor, it is capable of displaying the native resolution. Both my monitors are connected to DisplayPorts via a Dell dock. I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad, Windows 10, with Intel UHD graphics card.

I am using this Dell monitor:

https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-24-monitor-p2423d/apd/210-bdeg/monitors

And this dock:

https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/dell-dock-wd19s-130w/apd/210-azbx/docks

How can I resolve this? Do I need to use HDMI instead?

Comment: What have you tried other than disconnecting the one monitor? I am having a similar issue with the same dock type but different laptop and monitor, and have so far tried swapping cable input types, swapping the monitors, updating drivers, power cycling the monitor with the issue, swapping docks, and plugging the uncooperative monitor into the laptop directly. That worked as a work-around for us, but does not solve the core issue.

Comment: i got mine to work, on the Display window, click on your 2nd monitor and select Display resoultion, click on the various lower resolutions and by some chance your native one will be added.

Comment: I'll give that a go! Consider adding it as an answer, as well, so future users won't have to read our comments to find this worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work, on the Display window, click on your 2nd monitor and select Display resolution, click on the various lower resolutions and by some chance your native one will be added.

If this does not work then check the max Max Resolution (DP)  property of your processor, if its 7680x4320@60Hz and above, you should face no issue.
If its lower then your processor may not be able to support that much output.

I am using Intel® Core™ i7-10610U , with max DP resolution of
4096 x 2304@60Hz.